# Pre_split treats apostrophe like html entity

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm currently splitting utf8mb4_unicode_ci text outputted from my database by @, #, $, and spaces using the following method:

```
$textSplit = preg_split("/(?=[ @#$])/", $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

However, when I split a piece of database text with an apostrophe, I get the following output:

```
// $text is a database value that equals "Is this John's text?"
$textSplit = preg_split("/(?=[ @#$])/", $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

// Outputs array(5) { [0]=> string(2) "Is" [1]=> string(5) " this" [2]=> string(5) " John&" [3]=> string(6) "#039;s" [4]=> string(5) " text" }
var_dump($textSplit);
```

Is there anyway to prevent preg_split from treating the apostrophe like an html entity so that it splits up the text like this?

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(2) "Is" [1]=> string(5) " this" [2]=> string(7) " John's" [3]=> string(5) " text" }
```

Comment: While I don't know how to stop preg_split from this behaviour, this is easily fixable with a lookbehind.

Comment: Can you provide an example of `$text` ?

Comment: @Docteur Are you able to answer this question with some sample code that you believe would fix this issue so I can give it a try? If it works I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: It looks like you used `htmlentities` on the string before you stored it, try something like `$textSplit = preg_split("/(?=[ @#$])/", html_entity_decode($text), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`

Comment: @hwnd Sure, the first comment in my second code snippet specifies the value of $text. It's a variable from the database with the value "Is this John's text?"

Comment: @AlphaDelta html_entity_decode() didn't work but it got me on the right path. It looks like htmlspecialchars_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES) solved my problem. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone runs into this same issue, I was able to resolve it by using htmlspecialchars_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES). Thanks for everyone's help in getting to this solution!

Comment: Format code inline by encasing it in grave (\`) characters, like so `\`htmlspecialchars_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES)\``

Answer (score 0):

Try a lookbehind:

```
/(?<!&)(?=[ @#$])/
```

It won't match any character following &, preventing `&#xxx` to match.